# How to find common vertex count and sort the result in Gremlin?

Tags: java, cypher, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

My schema has 2 types of nodes ,

node1: Student (id is primary key)
node2: Skill(SkillName is primary key)
relation between them is HAS_SKILL

My use case:
For a given student Id , I need to get the similar users, skill count and list of common skills who have most skills match.

Query I have tried:

```java
g.V().has('Student','id','test1').
      out('HAS_SKILL').
      inE('HAS_SKILL').
      group().
        by(outV().values('userId')).
      unfold().
      project('id','count').
        by(select(keys)).
        by(select(values).count(local)).
      order().
        by('count',desc)
```

This query is giving similar users and counts bt I am not able to get common skill List .How to acheive that?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include the `addV` and `addE` steps that create a sample graph. That will allow people to give you tested answers. It would also be helpful to provide an example of the output you would like to generate. While people can most likely stare at the query and come up with suggestions, it's much nicer to be able to give you tested ones.

Comment: I went ahead and made a sample graph and provided an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using the steps below, I created a sample graph based on your question text.

```java
g.addV('Student').property('id','S1').as('s1').
  addV('Student').property('id','S2').as('s2').
  addV('Student').property('id','S3').as('s3').
  addV('Student').property('id','S4').as('s4').
  addV('Student').property('id','S5').as('s5').
  addV('Skill').property('SkillName','cricket').as('cr').
  addV('Skill').property('SkillName','football').as('fo').
  addV('Skill').property('SkillName','golf').as('go').
  addV('Skill').property('SkillName','volleyball').as('vo').
  addE('HAS_SKILL').from('s1').to('cr').
  addE('HAS_SKILL').from('s1').to('fo').
  addE('HAS_SKILL').from('s2').to('fo').
  addE('HAS_SKILL').from('s2').to('go').
  addE('HAS_SKILL').from('s3').to('fo').
  addE('HAS_SKILL').from('s3').to('cr').
  addE('HAS_SKILL').from('s3').to('vo').
  addE('HAS_SKILL').from('s4').to('cr').
  addE('HAS_SKILL').from('s5').to('fo')
```

Those steps build a graph that looks like this

[image: Sample Graph]

We can then find the list of common skills using a query along these lines.

```java
g.V().has('Student','id','S1').
      out('HAS_SKILL').as('common').
      in('HAS_SKILL').
      group().
        by('id').
        by(select('common').values('SkillName').fold()).unfold()
```

Which produces

```java
{'S3': ['cricket', 'football']}
{'S4': ['cricket']}
{'S5': ['football']}
{'S1': ['cricket', 'football']}
{'S2': ['football']}
```

From these building blocks you can then get the counts and any other required information.

```java
g.V().has('Student','id','S1').
      out('HAS_SKILL').as('common').
      in('HAS_SKILL').
      group().
        by('id').
        by(select('common').values('SkillName').fold()).
      unfold().
      project('id','count','skills').
        by(keys).
        by(select(values).count(local)).
        by(select(values)).
      order().
        by('count',desc)
```

Which gives us the final result

```java
{'id': 'S3', 'count': 2, 'skills': ['cricket', 'football']}
{'id': 'S1', 'count': 2, 'skills': ['cricket', 'football']}
{'id': 'S4', 'count': 1, 'skills': ['cricket']}
{'id': 'S5', 'count': 1, 'skills': ['football']}
{'id': 'S2', 'count': 1, 'skills': ['football']}
```

Comment: Tip: Instead of cutting and pasting the whole answer to see if it works (Kelvin's answer will always work), as a learning practice, I find it very useful to dissect the query by executing each step I type into the Gremlin console. For example, hit return after you type in the first `in(...)`.